# How to show a file at a specific revision?

Tags: git

As the question imply, I need to show a file from history at a specific commit, how would I be able to do so using command line? My repo is a git remote repo, with several pushes ..

I don't need to see differences, I just to view the whole file at that specific commit ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git show commitid:path/to/file
```

Comment: what if I want to copy all files of commitid out to a specific folder?

Comment: or at least to copy a file from that commitid out to some folder?

Comment: @simo: Just redirect the output of show to a file: `git show commitid:path/to/file > copy`